# Method canvas.rotate(90) applied to text is broken for android 4.0-4.1

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I tried to make text vertical with canvas.rotate() method. But on android 4.0 - 4.1 I got a "dancing letters", see screenshots. What is hapenning and how can I fix that? Please help me.

4.0 - 4.1 result:

[image]

Normal result:

[image]

Here is the code

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(30);
        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, -getWidth()/2, textPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: I see a difference there, but what is "dancing letters"?

Comment: Uploaded bigger images. It means that the same letters appear on different level(for example letter 'l' in 'Hello').

Comment: Have you tried to set the same font? Are both on the same dpi level?

Comment: This screenshots are from the same emulator and the same build, but first is with android 4.0, the second with 2.3. The same is on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can try it and:

Use `textView` and set `rotateAnimate` on it and `setDuration` minimum and set `setFillAfter(true)` like as below:

```
  RotateAnimation rt = new RotateAnimation(0, 90,textView.getLayoutParams().width/2,textView.getLayoutParams().height/2);
  rt.setDuration(1);                
  rt.setFillAfter(true);
  textView.startAnimation(rt);
```

it's so simple